# php mongodb select * from table where issue

Tags: php, mongodb

I would like to know how do I retrieve all items using one key in php mongo db, before we used to do like this in MySQL.

SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = $myvar

then I fetch everything, username and password, email ...etc

How can I achieve the same in mongodb, I searched but no answers.

Thank you all

Comment: what did you tried so far? Edit your question!

Comment: Most likely `$myvar` is a string, so you'd need `WHERE username = '$myvar'` (note the single-quotes around the variable). If you are using single-quotes around the entire `SELECT`-statement, variables aren't passed (only in double-quotes).

Answer (score 0):

In Mongodb, You just connect with db and go to collection and get all data in that collection. In Mongo DB, there is concept of collections and document. A document can  be treated as a row compared with MySQL. There can be thousands of documents in a collection. This is what i do in python. Same can be done in php too.

```
client = MongoClient()
db = client["db_name"]
collection = db["collection_name"].find() // without any key 
collection = db["collection_name"].find({"key":"name"}) // with any key
```

This will return all documents inside `collection` variable. You read all documents using for loop.

```
for document in collection:
     print document["name"], document["address"]
```

If you want just one document with some key. Try `db["collection_name"].find_one({"id":1})`

PHP use a mongodb extension to connect with db. By default, It is disable. You need to enable it first. First check, if mongodb extension is enable or not.